# Send request to azure inkrecognizer

Tags: python, python-requests, azure-cognitive-services

I have registered at the https://azure.microsoft.com/ru-ru/try/cognitive-services

From there I got an API-key and an endpoint https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/inkrecognizer

Here is my code:

```
import requests, json


subs_key = API_KEY
uri_base = 'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/inkrecognizer'
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json',
           "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": subs_key}

body = {}


response =requests.request('POST', uri_base, json=body, data=None, headers=headers)

print('Response:')
parsed =json.loads(response.text)
print(json.dumps(parsed, sort_keys=True, indent=2))
```

However it gives me

```
Response:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "404",
    "message": "Resource not found"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here how the code should look like:

```
import requests, json


subs_key = API_KEY
uri_base = 'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/inkrecognizer/v1.0-preview/recognize'
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json',
           "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": subs_key}

body = {}


response =requests.request('PUT', uri_base, json=body, data=None, headers=headers)

print('Response:')
parsed =json.loads(response.text)
print(json.dumps(parsed, sort_keys=True, indent=2))
```

And you will need to add into body `'language'` and `'strokes'`

[GIST](https://gist.github.com/trthhrtz/084f45a54c2b6d2f5dfcf08f5d10f3f0)